# Fancytree: How can I get input value in complex table?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, fancytree

[# this is reference picture #](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lTRU9.png)

#### I use complex table

```
$("#tree").fancytree({
checkbox: true,

.......

source: { url: "../tree-products.json"},

.......

renderColumns: function(event, data) {
    var node = data.node,$tdList = $(node.tr).find(">td");
    $tdList.eq(1).text(node.getIndexHier());
    $tdList.eq(3).find("select").val(node.data.unit);
    $tdList.eq(4).find("input").val(node.data.stusnextclassdate);
    $tdList.eq(5).find("input").val(node.data.mny);
    $tdList.eq(6).html(node.data.schedule);
}
```

})

#### The following is link for test

[test link](https://mido-9.com/fancytree-test/sample-multi-ext.html)

[This is google driver download link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1M4QwTlxUwdrmEnnaeJgHAU9sIL-QWdrv/view?usp=sharing)

#### My question is.....

when click button，need get fancytree input value. How should I write this fancytree syntax?

#### I had try the following syntax...

$("#tree").fancytree("getTree").getSelectedNodes()
above syntax can get tree-products.json data. Can't get data from renderColumns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you need to access the selection of your fancytree outside of the element. You can do that via

```
$("#tree").fancytree("getTree").getSelectedNodes()
```

This should return your selection in FancytreeNode objects.

For more information, see http://www.wwwendt.de/tech/fancytree/doc/jsdoc/Fancytree.html#getSelectedNodes

**EDIT**

OK, after seeing your code, I understand what you want to do and what you're doing wrong.

The issue is in your renderColumns method. In

```
$tdList.eq(3).find("input").val(node.key);
$tdList.eq(4).find("input").val(node.data.foo);
```

you're setting your node data in your html elements, but this not a 2-way binding. You need to update your node data when your input elements have changed their value. You can do that with javascript events:

```
renderColumns: function(event, data) {
    var node = data.node;
    var row = $(node.tr);

    $tdList = row.find(">td");
    // (Index #0 is rendered by fancytree by adding the checkbox)
    // Set column #1 info from node data:
    $tdList.eq(1).text(node.getIndexHier());
    // (Index #2 is rendered by fancytree)
    // Set column #3 info from node data:
    $tdList.eq(3).find("input").val(node.key);
    $tdList.eq(4).find("input").val(node.data.foo);

    row.on("change", ".update-foo", function() {
        node.data.foo = $(this).val();
    });
}
```

In order for this to work, you need to update your html template:

```
<tr>
    <td class="alignCenter"></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td><input name="input1" type="input"></td>
    <td><input class="update-foo" name="input2" type="input"></td>
    <td class="alignCenter"><input name="cb1" type="checkbox"></td>
    <td class="alignCenter"><input name="cb2" type="checkbox"></td>
    <td>
        <select name="sel1" id="">
            <option value="a">A</option>
            <option value="b">B</option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Alternatively, you can read the html tags in your buttons' click event, but I wouldn't reccomend that, since your node data isn't updated.

Hope this helps

Comment: jedemu115, Thank you for your reply. Your syntax can get tree-products.json data. Can't get data from renderColumns.

Comment: What data are you missing? Your array elements should contain nodes, so node.data should be accesible. $(node) should also be available for any json elements in the html.

Comment: I get an HTTP 404 when browsing to this link.

Is the webserver located at your internal network? If so, is it possible to make an example in something like jsfiddle or some other site I can reach?

Comment: I put a google driver link in the post, you can download it and test in your local network. Thank you very much.

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: Thank you so much, this is correct answer for me. This helps me a lot.